# How do you access a select pull down menu object with no ID or Class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

and then tell which selectedIndex was selected?!

here's the situation: the select object has no id or class. and the goal of the code is to make sure the user makes a selection before 'adding to cart'. further, this appears on many different product pages so the code needs to run not on the option value that was selected but rather on if the first option was selected or not. see below to clarify:

```
<select name="id[1]" id="attrib-1">//id cannot be used as it will be diff from page to     page
  <option value="20" selected="selected">Please Select</option>//can't be selected     when put into cart
  <option value="212" >Green</option>
  <option value="208">Yellow</option>
  <option value="210">Orange</option>
</select>

<input type="image" src="img/add.png" />//Add to cart button, has no id either.
```

this has to be triggered w/ an onclick of the 'add to cart' button. so my pseudo code would be:

```
$('input[type=image]').click(function(){
if(select option: is first option select) {
run some code} else (if anyother option other the first) {
run some diff code
}
```

thanks for the help. am spending way to much time on this, …uggg!

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, i got it

```
$('input[type=image]').click(function(){
    if ($("select > option:first").is(":selected")) {
        //run some code
} else  {
        //run some diff code
}
})
```